Adding a section of answers for each section of exercises at the end of a book using exercise package
I need add a section of answers for each section of exercises at the end of a book using exercise package. In each section the numbers of exercises are reset and actually i show de answer after the section.

Welcome to TeX SE. What have you tried? Could you add a small, but compilable, example of what you want to achieve?
